# Why am I unable to install the NppExec plugin for Notepad++?

Tags: windows-8, notepad++

I was trying to install the NppExec plugin for Notepad++ so that I can compile Java in it and run it. After the installation failed to work, I did some more research on compiling and decided to move on to using an IDE for Java. However, I still would like to know why Notepad++ did not let me install NppExec. Here's the issue:

I am told to navigate to Plugins --> Plugin Manager --> Show Plugin Manager and then scroll to NppExec. Whenever I click it and select Install, it gives me an error message saying "Installation of NppExec failed." I later clicked "Settings", which says:

**Plugin Config path is:
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\Config
Plugins in user's AppData directory are disabled - to enable in Notepad++ version 5.9.7 onwards place an empty file called allowAppDataPlugins.xml in the Notepad++ directory.**

I followed the instructions and created the allowAppDataPlugins.xml file, and put it into the Notepad++ directory. It didn't work.

Even now, the error message keeps popping up and disabling me from installing the plugin. Though I've gone on to an IDE, I'm still wondering in the back of my mind why this didn't work. Does anyone know why I couldn't install NppExec? How would I be able to? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

#### Why I can't I install NppExec?

You may need to have Admin rights to install plugins (depending on where Notepad++ is installed).

Try a manual install of the plugin (instructions below).

---

#### Manual install:

You may need to have admin rights to do this.

1. Close Notepad++
2. Download the zip file from http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/NppExec/
3. Extract to the Notepad++ plugins directory.
4. Run Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

If you just updated to the most recent version of Notepad, you will need to install the newest version of NppExec. As of now, I got `NppExec_06RC3_dll_PA.zip` from https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec/releases

As explained in the creator's Github page, after V.7.6.x, they changed the plugin folder format, so my previous version of NppExec was no longer being recognized.